# What does "support" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> Depending on the location, consideration should be given to providing
>   medical transportation, with qualified medical personnel, up to and
>   **including advanced life support**.

I am not sure if the bold part means "including advanced life support device" or if it refers to the medical personnel, which means that the medical personnel should also be qualified for advanced life support. Or does it mean "including advanced life support personnel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Life support is a specialized equipment used on patient who's one or more organs have stopped working. It is used to artificially supply oxygen until the organs begin to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Although technically grammatical, the sentence is somewhat nonsensical. It can be understood, but it's been phrased very poorly.

No matter how it's parsed, it doesn't make sense.

If we consider *with qualified medical personnel* to be a nonessential parenthetical information, then we're left with this:

> ✘ Consideration should be given to providing medical transportation up to and including advanced life support.

This makes no sense, because advanced life support is not a form of transportation.

---

If we consider *up to and including advanced life support* to be modifying *qualified medical personnel*, then we have this:

> ✘ Qualified medical personnel, up to and including advanced life support.

This also makes no sense, because advanced life support is not a type of personnel.

---

There are a few ways this could be rephrased so that it actually makes sense. Which one is *correct* depends on what is trying to be expressed—which isn't entirely clear.

> Depending on the location, consideration should be given to providing medical transportation with qualified medical personnel and advanced life support equipment.
>
> Depending on the location, consideration should be given to providing medical transportation, not only with qualified medical personnel but possibly advanced life support equipment.
>
> Depending on the location, consideration should be given to providing medical transportation with qualified medical personnel their equipment, up to and including advanced life support equipment.